# Hibernate creates a new sequence instead of using existing one and fails

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a preexisting Postgres database with a bunch of tables. Each table has an ID column with a sequence.
In my entity class I have something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "plan_block")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Audited
public class Block {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "plan_block_block_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "plan_block_block_id_seq", sequenceName = "plan_block_block_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "block_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
...
```

The sequence does exist in the database.
When I run the project I get

```
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create sequence "plan_block_block_id_seq" start with 1 increment by 1" via JDBC [ERROR: relation "plan_block_block_id_seq" already exists]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create sequence "plan_block_block_id_seq" start with 1 increment by 1" via JDBC [ERROR: relation "plan_block_block_id_seq" already exists]
```

for every single sequence I declared.

I tried adding strategy to GeneratedValue annotation, setting allocationSize or initialValue to the SequenceGenerator annotation.

UPD: I want to use that existing sequence because I already have a bunch of rows in the table

Comment: What is the value of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property. Should be = `none` in your case.

Comment: @Mar-Z I have it set to "update" because I do have some extra tables that are created by Spring

Comment: It is problematic. If you have an existing database filled with data and sequences then you should not allow Hibernate to update the schema. Maybe you should let Spring Boot create the additional tables for you? Or, even better - use Flyway for it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try in **application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= none
```

or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create
```

you can try in **application.yml**

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

or

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Answer (score 0):

It is showing "plan_block_block_id_seq" already exists, so try to drop that seq in your db. then run it again.

Comment: That is the point! I want to use that existing sequence because I already have some data there